# Compound - mantissa and exponent

Tags: compound-protocol

Trying to understand how the following example - from Compound Finance - works, in case you are trying to store something of order 1x10^19.

From GitHub - https://github.com/compound-finance/compound-money-market/blob/master/contracts/Exponential.sol

“Exp is a struct which stores decimals with a fixed precision of 18 decimal places.

- ```
      Thus, if we wanted to store the 5.1, mantissa would store 5.1e18. That is:
  ```
- ```
      `Exp({mantissa: 5100000000000000000})`.”
  ```

By the logic above, does this mean that if you were trying to store, say, 10 or above, you wouldn’t be able to put it in Exp({mantissa}), since that’d have a length of 19?

Comment: See the Compound docs on [protocol math](https://compound.finance/docs#protocol-math).

Comment: 10 in the decimal format is 10000000000000000000 (1e19) in the Exp format. 10 in the Exp format is 0.00000000000000001 (1e-17) in the decimal format. This is analogous to [the way units work for ETH](https://www.etherchain.org/tools/unitConverter).